# NextJS 13 - 404 This page could not be found. App router in dev mode

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a project in NextJS 13 with the App Router which is throwing the 404: Not Found Error although the layout.tsx elements work. This is on both the index page and subsequent router pages. Here is my next config, the directory and the page output. This is in development mode with dynamic routing.

Unfortunately i'm really dumbfounded how this actually happened (I was about to static export with generateStaticParams, then ran into issues, but now the whole project is broken even) so i don't know what evidence exactly to post, but please let me know if you can!

[image]

[image: The]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the tsconfig.json file and everything worked.